# ListItemVersion content type read in SharePoint2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In SP2010, create a `DocLib` which supports Content Types (add the Dublin Core Document content type, and set it as the default CT) and enable supports Versions.
similarly add another content type Link to document

Create a document which uses the Dublin Core CT.
Publish it as version 1

Edit the properties of the document and change content type ko LInk to document 
Publish it as version 2

Now from Code when I try to read fields of the items (latest version) i can read content type using code

```
object val = spItem[field.Id]
```

But in case of versioned document I used this code

```
object val = spItem[field.InternalName];
```

but unfortunately the content type value was `null` .

How to read content type of version document.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to get the content type, simple call `spItem.ContentType`, but I probably have missed something in your question.

Comment: spItem in infact SPListItemVersion so i cannot call spItem.ContentType.

Comment: Do make the question more clear, please add relevant code. We can't guess how you build your objects.

Comment: `spItem.ListItem.ContentType` try [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion_members.aspx)

Comment: Hi , the scenario is like this 


` SPListItem spItem=....;//created spItem here 
 SPListItemVersionCollection versionCollection =   spItem.Versions;
  foreach (SPListItemVersion listItemVersion in versionCollection)
        {
 foreach (SPField field in listItemVersion .Fields)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (field.Type != SPFieldType.PageSeparator)
                    {
                    object val = listItemVersion field.InternalName];
                    }

                }
           }
       }
`

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question, and have seen this bug.

Unfortunately, SharePoint 2013 seems to have the same bug (namely that the ContentType field is not populated in SPListItemVersion).

The ContentTypeId field does seem to be populated, so as a workaround, one can hardcode tests against the ContentTypeId.

Comment: How random! At least the ContentTypeId field is there. Thanks!